# Google Maps API: Trying to drop multiple markers using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, but this is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var locations = [
            ['Passage Island', 49.343085, -123.305938],
            ['Point Atkinson', 49.329925, -123.264994]
        ];

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.343085, -123.305938),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

        var marker, i;

        for(i=0; i < locations.length; i++){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
</script>
```

Before I tried using the array to drop markers, I was able to load up the map with markers. But each marker was `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({....` so I figured that I should be  using arrays if I want to do more than one marker. And now since I have started trying to use arrays, the map won't even load to begin with. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As you are new user here, let me inform you, if you find the solution of your problem or you can say answer to your question, then you should accept the answer here, to help others know about the solution which worked for you. To accept you should click on the tick sign below the up down arrows near each answer. You can accept only one answer per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't include this line: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` inside a function if it is not being called on `load`. Your code is fine except that you called the `initialize` function from within itself , hence it's not getting called at all.

Place `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` outside the function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/pGBZD/160/

Comment: We had difference in seconds for the answer but +1 for the fiddle. Good Work !

Answer (score 2):

I think you have written `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` statement inside your `initialize()` function. You should write it outside.